# Fitting image to background

Tags: java, android, background

I want to use an image which is smaller than width of the screen, but has height bigger than the screen. I was thinking to use scroll view, that the whole image could be used, but fitting changes original ratio of the picture. How can I make it to adjust width and increase height by the same ratio? Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/tutorial"
  > 
  <ScrollView
    android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:scaleType="fitXY"
  android:src="@drawable/tutorial">
  </ImageView>
  </ScrollView>   
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you don't use **fill_parent** you want use **match_parent**
>
> `<ImageView
>       android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent"
>     android:backround="@drawable/tutorial"/>`

Comment: Using match parent and fitXY it does the same,picture is scaled, but it becomes broader, but not longer. Using nothing and centerInside it picture keeps right ratio, but it isn't wide enough

Comment: it doesn't scale properly. Only one dimension is good at every single time. If width is alright, it somehow cuts some height. If height is good, then the picture is not over the whole width. And this is what I get for every single method I have used

Comment: y r u give height 3505, which screen u use. small or large screen frnd

Comment: I want that it would scale this picture automatically

Comment: What is the maximum height? The problem is that I need it too be big

Answer (score 0):

use `android:scaleType="CENTER_INSIDE"` in Your `Imageview` thats it.

for more details 
[read more about CENTER_INSIDE here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)